# ClassNotFoundException: org/springframework/beans/factory/SmartInitializingSingletonCustomizer

Tags: spring, jvm, crash-reports, jvm-crash

Following is error log file content, anybody help me？thanks

---

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006e7ea1be, pid=17964, tid=0x00000000000046d8
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x14a1be]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001c619000):  JavaThread "Disp-1" [_thread_in_vm, id=18136, stack(0x000000001df70000,0x000000001e070000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000900, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000001e06e190, RBP=0x000000001e06f2a8, RSI=0x000000001c6191f8, RDI=0x000000001c619000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x000000001a2fafb8, R10=0x000000001d410550, R11=0x00000000d696d810
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000001d7e55a8, R14=0x000000001e06f2d0, R15=0x000000001c619000
RIP=0x000000006e7ea1be, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001e06e190)
0x000000001e06e190:   000000001db87860 000000006e7fc623
0x000000001e06e1a0:   0000b1be7181fe0f 000000006e7e13cd
0x000000001e06e1b0:   000000001d7e55a8 000000001c6191f8
0x000000001e06e1c0:   000000001c619000 000000006e7ddd28
0x000000001e06e1d0:   000000001c619000 0000000000000000
0x000000001e06e1e0:   0000000000000000 000000001c619000
0x000000001e06e1f0:   0000000000000000 0000000002a3460c
0x000000001e06e200:   000000001d7e55b0 000000001e06f2a8
0x000000001e06e210:   000000001c619000 000000001e06f2a8
0x000000001e06e220:   000000001d410aa0 000000001c6191f8
0x000000001e06e230:   000000001dbac750 0000000000000034
0x000000001e06e240:   000000001d410aa0 000000001a2fafc8
0x000000001e06e250:   0000000002c9835d 000000001c619000
0x000000001e06e260:   000000001d7e55b0 0000000002a3446f
0x000000001e06e270:   000000001c6191f8 000000001db87860
0x000000001e06e280:   0000000000000000 000000001a2fafb8 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006e7ea1be)
0x000000006e7ea19e:   00 48 83 7f 08 00 48 89 7c 24 58 48 c7 44 24 60
0x000000006e7ea1ae:   00 00 00 00 74 0a 48 8d 4c 24 58 e8 02 18 13 00
0x000000006e7ea1be:   48 8b 0b e8 aa e3 f1 ff 4c 8b c7 33 d2 48 8b d8
0x000000006e7ea1ce:   48 8b 00 48 8b cb ff 50 78 48 83 7f 08 00 74 04 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000900 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001e06e190 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001c619000
RBP=0x000000001e06f2a8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000001c619000
RSI=0x000000001c6191f8 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000000001c619000 is a thread
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000001a2fafb8 is an unknown value
R10=0x000000001d410550 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000d696d810 is an oop

[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005]

Stack: [0x000000001df70000,0x000000001e070000],  sp=0x000000001e06e190,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x14a1be]
C  [tibrvj.dll+0x446f]
C  [tibrvj.dll+0x46fe]
C  [tibrvj.dll+0x6357]
C  [tibrvcmq.dll+0xad17]
C  [tibrv.dll+0x4ce28]
C  [tibrv.dll+0x4d4a5]
C  [tibrv.dll+0x4d633]
C  [tibrvj.dll+0x16f6]
C  0x0000000002ca7f74

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvImplQueueC.natDispatch(I)V+0
j  com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvImplQueueC.dispatch()V+5
j  com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvQueue.dispatch()V+14
j  com.tibco.tibrv.TibrvDispatcher.run()V+112
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x000000001c619000 JavaThread "Disp-1" [_thread_in_vm, id=18136, stack(0x000000001df70000,0x000000001e070000)]
  0x000000001778c000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=416, stack(0x00000000193f0000,0x00000000194f0000)]
  0x000000001774d000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16164, stack(0x00000000192f0000,0x00000000193f0000)]
  0x000000001774c000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7268, stack(0x00000000191f0000,0x00000000192f0000)]
  0x0000000017747000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15800, stack(0x00000000190f0000,0x00000000191f0000)]
  0x0000000017745800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18400, stack(0x0000000018ff0000,0x00000000190f0000)]
  0x0000000018b33800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14912, stack(0x0000000018ef0000,0x0000000018ff0000)]
  0x000000001771a800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9832, stack(0x0000000018990000,0x0000000018a90000)]
  0x0000000002c7f000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12364, stack(0x0000000018890000,0x0000000018990000)]
  0x0000000002b90800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=13568, stack(0x0000000002a90000,0x0000000002b90000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000176f8000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000018790000,0x0000000018890000] [id=16944]
  0x0000000018bb6000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000194f0000,0x00000000195f0000] [id=1016]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 70656K, used 12341K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000dad00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 11% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d6a113e8,0x00000000da300000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000da800000,0x00000000dacfc060,0x00000000dad00000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000da300000,0x00000000da300000,0x00000000da800000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 1328K [0x0000000082800000, 0x0000000087c00000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 86016K, 1% used [0x0000000082800000,0x000000008294c390,0x0000000087c00000)
 Metaspace       used 15572K, capacity 15896K, committed 16128K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1932K, capacity 2012K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012050000,0x0000000012440000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011c3c000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000006eebb6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012ae0000, 0x0000000014a40000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014a40000, 0x00000000169a0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000002670000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=7054Kb max_used=7082Kb free=238705Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002c90000, 0x0000000003390000, 0x0000000011c90000]
 total_blobs=2306 nmethods=1958 adapters=260
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 3.200 Thread 0x000000001774c000 nmethod 1721 0x000000000335a690 code [0x000000000335a7c0, 0x000000000335a818]
Event: 3.200 Thread 0x000000001774c000 1954       4       java.util.AbstractMap::<init> (5 bytes)
Event: 3.200 Thread 0x000000001774c000 nmethod 1954 0x0000000003357a90 code [0x0000000003357bc0, 0x0000000003357c18]
Event: 3.200 Thread 0x000000001774c000 1790       4       java.util.LinkedList$ListItr::hasNext (20 bytes)
Event: 3.201 Thread 0x000000001774c000 nmethod 1790 0x0000000003357850 code [0x0000000003357980, 0x0000000003357a18]
Event: 3.201 Thread 0x000000001774c000 1654       4       java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator::next (5 bytes)
Event: 3.203 Thread 0x000000001774c000 nmethod 1654 0x000000000335b990 code [0x000000000335bae0, 0x000000000335bcb8]
Event: 3.203 Thread 0x000000001774c000 1657       4       org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor::getAnnotationAttributes (50 bytes)
Event: 3.207 Thread 0x000000001774c000 nmethod 1657 0x000000000335d290 code [0x000000000335d400, 0x000000000335d698]
Event: 3.221 Thread 0x0000000017747000 nmethod 1656 0x00000000033729d0 code [0x0000000003372ee0, 0x00000000033791e0]

GC Heap History (8 events):
Event: 1.198 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 37888K, used 32768K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000d8d00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 32768K, 100% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8300000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8800000,0x00000000d8800000,0x00000000d8d00000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8800000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 0K [0x0000000082800000, 0x0000000087c00000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 86016K, 0% used [0x0000000082800000,0x0000000082800000,0x0000000087c00000)
 Metaspace       used 8557K, capacity 8842K, committed 9088K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 1058K, capacity 1119K, committed 1152K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 1.206 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 37888K, used 4074K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000d8d00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 32768K, 0% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d8300000)
  from space 5120K, 79% used [0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d86fa8d8,0x00000000d8800000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8800000,0x00000000d8800000,0x00000000d8d00000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 80K [0x0000000082800000, 0x0000000087c00000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 86016K, 0% used [0x0000000082800000,0x0000000082814010,0x0000000087c00000)
 Metaspace       used 8557K, capacity 8842K, committed 9088K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 1058K, capacity 1119K, committed 1152K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2.106 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 37888K, used 36842K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000d8d00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 32768K, 100% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8300000)
  from space 5120K, 79% used [0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d86fa8d8,0x00000000d8800000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8800000,0x00000000d8800000,0x00000000d8d00000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 80K [0x0000000082800000, 0x0000000087c00000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 86016K, 0% used [0x0000000082800000,0x0000000082814010,0x0000000087c00000)
 Metaspace       used 13165K, capacity 13474K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1653K, capacity 1747K, committed 1792K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2.113 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 37888K, used 5106K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000d8d00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 32768K, 0% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d8300000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000d8800000,0x00000000d8cfc860,0x00000000d8d00000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8800000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 473K [0x0000000082800000, 0x0000000087c00000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 86016K, 0% used [0x0000000082800000,0x0000000082876530,0x0000000087c00000)
 Metaspace       used 13165K, capacity 13474K, committed 13568K, reserved 1060864K
  class space    used 1653K, capacity 1747K, committed 1792K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2.487 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 37888K, used 37874K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000d8d00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 32768K, 100% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8300000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000d8800000,0x00000000d8cfc860,0x00000000d8d00000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8800000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 473K [0x0000000082800000, 0x0000000087c00000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 86016K, 0% used [0x0000000082800000,0x0000000082876530,0x0000000087c00000)
 Metaspace       used 13907K, capacity 14176K, committed 14336K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1720K, capacity 1784K, committed 1792K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2.496 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 37888K, used 5032K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000dad00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 32768K, 0% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d8300000)
  from space 5120K, 98% used [0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d87ea1b0,0x00000000d8800000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000da800000,0x00000000da800000,0x00000000dad00000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 481K [0x0000000082800000, 0x0000000087c00000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 86016K, 0% used [0x0000000082800000,0x0000000082878530,0x0000000087c00000)
 Metaspace       used 13907K, capacity 14176K, committed 14336K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1720K, capacity 1784K, committed 1792K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 2.911 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=4 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 37888K, used 37800K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000dad00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 32768K, 100% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d8300000)
  from space 5120K, 98% used [0x00000000d8300000,0x00000000d87ea1b0,0x00000000d8800000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000da800000,0x00000000da800000,0x00000000dad00000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 481K [0x0000000082800000, 0x0000000087c00000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 86016K, 0% used [0x0000000082800000,0x0000000082878530,0x0000000087c00000)
 Metaspace       used 15169K, capacity 15480K, committed 15616K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1891K, capacity 1980K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2.922 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=4 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 70656K, used 5104K [0x00000000d6300000, 0x00000000dad00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 65536K, 0% used [0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000d6300000,0x00000000da300000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000da800000,0x00000000dacfc060,0x00000000dad00000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000da300000,0x00000000da300000,0x00000000da800000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 1328K [0x0000000082800000, 0x0000000087c00000, 0x00000000d6300000)
  object space 86016K, 1% used [0x0000000082800000,0x000000008294c390,0x0000000087c00000)
 Metaspace       used 15169K, capacity 15480K, committed 15616K, reserved 1062912K
  class space    used 1891K, capacity 1980K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 2.145 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000030441fc method=java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 37
Event: 2.145 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000030441fc method=java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 37
Event: 2.145 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=predicate action=maybe_recompile pc=0x0000000003026da8 method=java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Ljava/util/regex/Matcher;ILjava/lang/CharSequence;)Z @ 21
Event: 2.523 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003247108 method=java.util.AbstractCollection.isEmpty()Z @ 4
Event: 2.524 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003261fd0 method=org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.convertClassValues(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/annotation/Ann
Event: 2.683 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x00000000030f7a68 method=java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 192
Event: 2.813 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000030f7ae4 method=java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 206
Event: 2.989 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000030ec124 method=java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine()I @ 180
Event: 3.017 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003179698 method=java.lang.String.startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z @ 25
Event: 3.017 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000002e2ca94 method=java.lang.String.startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z @ 25

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 2.974 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/springframework/beans/factory/SmartInitializingSingletonCustomizer> (0x00000000d66e33c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDict
Event: 2.974 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAwareCustomizer> (0x00000000d66f6548) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cp
Event: 2.975 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': java/lang/ObjectCustomizer> (0x00000000d6701db0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 2.976 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/springframework/context/event/DefaultEventListenerFactoryCustomizer> (0x00000000d6719af8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDic
Event: 2.976 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactoryCustomizer> (0x00000000d6733d78) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary
Event: 2.977 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/springframework/core/OrderedCustomizer> (0x00000000d6746268) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 2.977 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': java/lang/ObjectCustomizer> (0x00000000d6751a50) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.cpp, line 210]
Event: 2.978 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/example/ControllerDemo/ControllerDemoApplicationCustomizer> (0x00000000d6767c20) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\share\vm\classfile\systemDictionary.c
Event: 2.978 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': com/example/ControllerDemo/ControllerDemoApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b10776ccCustomizer> (0x00000000d6781448) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\shar
Event: 2.979 Thread 0x0000000002b90800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ClassNotFoundException': org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer$EnhancedConfigurationCustomizer> (0x00000000d679f4c8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u121\8372\hotspot\src\sh

Events (10 events):
Event: 3.025 loading class com/tibco/tibrv/TibrvImplCmTPortC done
Event: 3.031 loading class com/tibco/tibrv/TibrvCmListener
Event: 3.031 loading class com/tibco/tibrv/TibrvCmListener done
Event: 3.035 loading class com/tibco/tibrv/TibrvDispatcher
Event: 3.035 loading class com/tibco/tibrv/TibrvDispatcher done
Event: 3.037 loading class com/tibco/tibrv/TibrvQueueGroup
Event: 3.037 loading class com/tibco/tibrv/TibrvQueueGroup done
Event: 3.038 Thread 0x000000001c619000 Thread added: 0x000000001c619000
Event: 4.093 Executing VM operation: EnableBiasedLocking
Event: 4.093 Executing VM operation: EnableBiasedLocking done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6d9c80000 - 0x00007ff6d9cb7000     C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
0x00007ffd2dde0000 - 0x00007ffd2dfbb000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffd2b780000 - 0x00007ffd2b82e000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffd2a650000 - 0x00007ffd2a899000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffd2b3b0000 - 0x00007ffd2b451000     C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffd2d5e0000 - 0x00007ffd2d67d000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffd2b6f0000 - 0x00007ffd2b749000     C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffd2cf70000 - 0x00007ffd2d095000     C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffd2d490000 - 0x00007ffd2d5da000     C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffd2b270000 - 0x00007ffd2b28e000     C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffd2ddb0000 - 0x00007ffd2ddd7000     C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffd2a410000 - 0x00007ffd2a597000     C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffd2a370000 - 0x00007ffd2a40a000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffd2a8a0000 - 0x00007ffd2a996000     C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffd080c0000 - 0x00007ffd08327000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.483_none_26002d27e7c744a2\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffd2d110000 - 0x00007ffd2d409000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffd2a300000 - 0x00007ffd2a36a000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffd2b8f0000 - 0x00007ffd2b91d000     C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x000000006fe40000 - 0x000000006ff12000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006e6a0000 - 0x000000006ef3b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffd2b3a0000 - 0x00007ffd2b3a8000     C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffd1e1b0000 - 0x00007ffd1e1ba000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffd227c0000 - 0x00007ffd227e3000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffd12a10000 - 0x00007ffd12a19000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffd2d0a0000 - 0x00007ffd2d10c000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffd22640000 - 0x00007ffd2266b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\winmmbase.dll
0x00007ffd2a5a0000 - 0x00007ffd2a5e9000     C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000070b20000 - 0x0000000070b2f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006fff0000 - 0x0000000070019000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.dll
0x000000006ffd0000 - 0x000000006ffe6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffd2ba80000 - 0x00007ffd2ceb7000     C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffd2cec0000 - 0x00007ffd2cf6a000     C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffd2ab70000 - 0x00007ffd2b261000     C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffd2b340000 - 0x00007ffd2b391000     C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffd2a250000 - 0x00007ffd2a261000     C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffd2a290000 - 0x00007ffd2a2dc000     C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffd2a2e0000 - 0x00007ffd2a2f5000     C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
0x000000006e690000 - 0x000000006e69d000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\management.dll
0x000000006e670000 - 0x000000006e68a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffd29b00000 - 0x00007ffd29b5c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ffd1d840000 - 0x00007ffd1d856000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x00007ffd1d820000 - 0x00007ffd1d83a000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x00007ffd24140000 - 0x00007ffd24158000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x00007ffd298e0000 - 0x00007ffd29984000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x00007ffd2b750000 - 0x00007ffd2b758000     C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffd298a0000 - 0x00007ffd298d7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ffd1d810000 - 0x00007ffd1d81e000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x00007ffd1d7f0000 - 0x00007ffd1d805000     C:\Windows\System32\wshbth.dll
0x00007ffd1d7e0000 - 0x00007ffd1d7ea000     C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
0x00007ffd22940000 - 0x00007ffd229ab000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x00007ffd2a120000 - 0x00007ffd2a145000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x0000000002a30000 - 0x0000000002a41000     C:\tibco\tibrv\8.4\bin\tibrvj.dll
0x0000000070a50000 - 0x0000000070b19000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.9307_none_88daf3492fb349de\MSVCR80.dll
0x0000000002a60000 - 0x0000000002a75000     C:\tibco\tibrv\8.4\bin\tibrvcmq.dll
0x000000001c040000 - 0x000000001c0ca000     C:\tibco\tibrv\8.4\bin\tibrv.dll
0x000000001c0d0000 - 0x000000001c0f2000     C:\tibco\tibrv\8.4\bin\tibrvcm.dll
0x000000001c120000 - 0x000000001c12d000     C:\tibco\tibrv\8.4\bin\tibrvft.dll
0x00007ffd2a150000 - 0x00007ffd2a180000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ffd244c0000 - 0x00007ffd24669000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
java_command: ControllerDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
java_class_path (initial): ControllerDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
CLASSPATH=C:\tibco\tibrv\8.4\lib\tibrvnative.jar;.;C:\Users\YaQingHe\AppData\Local\Temp\LREC93D.tmp\lib\dt.jar;C:\Users\YaQingHe\AppData\Local\Temp\LREC93D.tmp\lib\tools.jar;
PATH=C:\app\YaQingHe\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\tibco\tibrv\8.4\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;"C:\Users\YaQingHe\AppData\Local\Temp\LREC93D.tmp\bin;C:\Users\YaQingHe\AppData\Local\Temp\LREC93D.tmp\jre\bin;";C:\0\project\csot\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\0\project\csot\apache-activemq-5.15.0\bin;C:\Users\YaQingHe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
USERNAME=YaQingHe
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 15063 (10.0.15063.296)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 142 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 8223584k(2894684k free), swap 12024672k(1774324k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_121-b13), built on Dec 12 2016 18:21:36 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Fri Mar 02 15:49:06 2018
elapsed time: 15 seconds (0d 0h 0m 15s)
```

Comment: What were you doing with what software when this happened? Please provide some details.

Comment: problem happen at the program received a message from tibco EMS. the program dependency the tibco client jar.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark answer since there is not much info:

I had a similar problem, jvm crashed when receiving TIB-reply, after upgrading tib client stuff from 8.1.2 to 8.3+.
What helped me was to use tibrvnative.jar instead of tibrvj.jar.

Answer (score -1):

Could you provide additional info about external dependencies that you are using? Try to use compatible versions of dependencies.

Comment: Running as a jar is failed(java -jar xxx.jar) ,but running program in eclipse as a java application is ok. problem happen at the program received a  message from tibco EMS. the program dependency the tibco client jar.